# codeigniter ajax url error

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem when sending data with ajax,in the URL it adds .php to my controller

need help :(

this is the AJAX script to make call to Welcome controller:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#palier').change(function(){
   var idf=$(this).val();
 console.log(idf);
    $.ajax({
       url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"Welcome/affectation_exam",
       type : "POST",
       data:{idf:idf},
       datatype:"text",
       success:function(data){
           $('#specialite').html(data); 
          // console.log(data);
       }


    });

});
})

</script>
```

in the controller i have :

```
public function affectation_exam($page='affectation des examens')
  {

    $data['title']=$page;

      $this->load->model('Palier');
      $this->load->model('Specialite');
      $data['records']=$this->Specialite->get_specialite();
      $data['palier']=$this->Palier->get_palier();
      $this->load->view('template/main',$data);
      echo $_POST["idf"];


  }
```

Comment: May be Slash is missing in url. "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"/Welcome/affectation_exam"

Comment: you need to pass csrf token along with the post request

Comment: i didn't anderstand  .. can u show me an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$.ajax({      
  url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/welcome/affectation_exam";
  ...
});
```

If you have not removed `index.php` then use it as

```
$.ajax({      
  url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/welcome/affectation_exam";
  ...
});
```

---

**Edited**

Change your controller code like

```
public function affectation_exam($page='affectation des examens')
{

    $data['title']=$page;
    $this->load->model('Palier');
    $this->load->model('Specialite');
    $data['records']=$this->Specialite->get_specialite();
    $data['palier']=$this->Palier->get_palier();
    $result = $this->load->view('template/main',$data, TRUE);
    //$_POST["idf"];
    echo $result; exit;

}
```

Comment: doesn't work  its sending welcome.php/affectation_exam .. ...is that a problem with htaccess ?

Comment: Yes it might be htaccess problem. did you removed `index.php`?. Check my updated answer.

Comment: yep ... i have this :                                                                     RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|resources|assets|css|img|js|fonts|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: did you set `$config['index_page'] = "";` in config.php file?

Comment: yes i did ... acctually  the url welcome/affectation_exam work  but the problem  is that its sending welcome.php and that url does't much any page (404)

Comment: Ok, If you run `BASE_URL/welcome/affectation_exam` directly in browser its working or not?

Comment: i just loaded the view and  model BTW i don't know how to add code on comments -_-

Comment: done!  the idf is undefined cus its not sending at the good URL ... i can't send you screenshot :(

Comment: Check my edited answer, Why you have printed `echo $_POST["idf"];` ? @Lollita

Comment: because i'm sending idf to the controller ... so i checked if i received it ... what is $result ??

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no requirement for concatenation of URL string.

2) The controller name needs to be in lower-case.

```
$.ajax({
       url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/affectation_exam",
       .....
     });
```

Comment: may be there is some issue with your htaccess file. Also does in console it show .php extension ?

Comment: yep and the page does not exist:  404page not found

Comment: check `$config['url_suffix']` variable in your `config.php`. It should be set to empty string.